# Select multiple values from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T3.Val FROM Table1 as T1
INNER JOIN Table2 as T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
```

My problem is that the last Inner Join returns 3 rows and i want to print all of those values like T3.val1, T3.val2, T3.val3

How is that done?

EDIT: Example data:
T3

```
DataID, DefinitionID, ItemID, UnitID, Val,    TS
123     111           4541    45545   0.05    2016-05-07 06:14:07
124     111           5487    69587   0.026   2016-05-07 09:11:01
125     111           3621    12862   0       2016-05-07 10:04:17
```

This is now my query:

```
SELECT t1.EventID, group_concat(t3.Val) FROM T1 as t1
INNER JOIN T2 as t2 ON t1.EventID = t2.EventID
INNER JOIN T3 as t3 on t2.DefinitionID = t3.DefinitionID
GROUP BY t3.Val;
```

And the result is:

```
EventID   group_concat(t3.val)
3         0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0........
```

Comment: make them in the select list.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: It seems like you got what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(T3.Val,',') FROM Table1 as T1
INNER JOIN Table2 as T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
GROUP BY T3.ID
```

---

```
Table1
---------------------
ID
1

Table2
---------------------
ID
1


Table3
---------------------
ID    Val
1      A
1      B
1      C
```

**Output**

```
ID   Val
1    A,B,C
```

Comment: It did, thank you! What if I wanted to sum the values instead of printing them all.Is that possible as well?

Comment: Yes you can use SUM().http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html